# org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable cannot be cast to MyEntity

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm experimenting with DataTable - Cell Editing as shown in [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf) and I want to save the modified object 
the method `onCellEdit` is definied as follows:

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
       Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
       Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
       Matpilotaccess mpltiacc = (Matpilotaccess)event.getSource();
       articleDAO.Updatetable(mpltiacc);
       //event.getSource();
       System.out.println("///////////////////////"+event.getOldValue());
       System.out.println("///////////////////////"+event.getNewValue());
}
```

the  Matpilotaccess class is definied as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="matpilotaccess")
public class Matpilotaccess implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="idmatpilotaccess1")
    private int idmatpilotaccess1;
    @Column(name="serie")
    private String serie;
    @Column(name="cap")
    private int cap;
    @Column(name="cal")
    private String cal;
    @Column(name="classe")
    private int classe;
    @Column(name="unite")
    private String unite;
    @Column(name="puhtva")
    private float puhtva;

    @Column(name="puttc")
    private float puttc;
    @Column(name="quantite")
    private float quantite;
    @Column(name="monthtva")
    private float monthtva;
    @Column(name="montttc")
    private float montttc;


    public Matpilotaccess1(int idmatpilotaccess1, String serie, int cap,
            String cal, int classe, String unite, float puhtva, float puttc,
            float quantite, float monthtva, float montttc) {
        super();
        this.idmatpilotaccess1 = idmatpilotaccess1;
        this.serie = serie;
        this.cap = cap;
        this.cal = cal;
        this.classe = classe;
        this.unite = unite;
        this.puhtva = puhtva;
        this.puttc = puttc;
        this.quantite = quantite;
        this.monthtva = monthtva;
        this.montttc = montttc;
    }
    public Matpilotaccess1() {
        super();
    }

    //getters and setters



}
```

and the following exception is thrown:

```
org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable cannot be cast to com.pfe.model.Matpilotaccess
```

How can I proceed to cast primefacesDatatable to Matpilotaccess (My entity)?

Comment: event.getSource() will return a DataTable, why are you casting it to your own type?

Comment: @JamesB because i want to replace the old object by the modified object

Comment: You have already retrieved the new value using getNewValue(). You need to set this onto your custom class before saving it. Could you post the Matpilotaccess class?

Comment: Yes , you find it in the edited question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Replacing the old object by the modified one*" means updating an Entity object not updating the whole entities (datatable), so this should be enough :

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
    ...
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Matpilotaccess mpltiacc  = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{mpltiacc}", Matpilotaccess.class);  
    articleDAO.Updatetable(mpltiacc);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I suspect event.getNewValue() will return a String which is the value for one of the properties of Matpilotaccess. Only the OP can confirm this thought.

Comment: It seems it returns `Object`.. i'd like rather to mean modifying a property at the 1st time and not the Entity object. Thanks to indicate that.

Comment: Have you debugged the application to see what type is actually returned at runtime?

Comment: @Omar it throws this error  `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String` and the error comes from  `String new_serie = (String) event.getNewValue();`

Comment: @JamesB yes it returns Object

Comment: @BellilMedSamouel, see updated answer, there's no need to set the properties' new values twice.

Comment: excuse me in Matpilotaccess `mpltiacc  = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{mpltiacc}", Matpilotaccess.class);` do you mean `contest.getApplication` ?? if it's context , i see a lot classes  named context example `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.Context` and `Java.entreprise.context` i'll be grateful is you tell me which one !!

Comment: oups! typing mistake, it should be context, not contest while defining in the line above.